# Including other packaged software with C# installation

Tags: c#, installation

I know how to create setup files and which files I need to take from which folders, but what if we want to add extra 3rd party software with our installation.  How can we go about doing this?

For example, suppose my software requires WinRar and the user does not have it installed.  How can I add it through the setup file of my C# project?

Comment: You would launch the setup and provide the user the option of installing the software.  Unless the third-party software provides a library for this service, I can guarantee you that the company behind the third-party program, will not appreciate you sending out specfic versions of their product yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly off topic from what you asked, but I would advise you to be very careful abpout distributing third party software as part of you setup.  The list of potential pitfals of doing so include (but is not limited to)

1) falling foul of 3rd party licencing restrictions
2) Inadvertently distrubuting viruses
3) accidental overwriting of a user's current version of software (may be you include version 4 of a package, but for some reason the user requires version 3 for compatibility reasons)

If you have 3rd party requirements in your software, by all means check for them during installation / 1st run, but prompt the user that they need to download / install the components separately rather than trying to automatically do it for them

Comment: So can i do this way: like i give setup file of my project and include required software 's setup with separate and provide the ReadMe file to instruct users, to install the required folder it those are not installed in their computer  ?

Comment: You *can* do anything you like, but my point is that there are pitfalls with distributing someone else's software in this way.  Safest way is to pop up a message to say "XZY is required - download it from <vendor's website> and install it"